# An object in 2 Lists does not get found in one

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some strange behaviour I can't explain:
I have a List of Ellipsis in a WPF-Canvas, which I'd like to make blink.
For performances purpose, I add newly created stars to the Canvas (which holds more objects) and to a local list. This means I can work just with the local List and dont have to recheck the Children-Collection every time.
My code is looking like this:

```
    private const Int32 STAR_COUNT = 500;
    private readonly double STAR_MOVE_RATE = GameObject.OBJECTS_MOVE_RATE/2;
    private readonly Timer _blinkingTimer = new Timer();
    private readonly Canvas _gameField;
    private readonly List<Ellipse> _stars = new List<Ellipse>();

    public StarHandler(Canvas gameField)
    {
        _gameField = gameField;
        _blinkingTimer.Interval = 70;
        _blinkingTimer.Elapsed += _blinkingTimer_Elapsed;

        for (int i = 0; i < STAR_COUNT; i++)
            AddSetStar(StarFactory.CreateStar());
        _blinkingTimer.Start();
    }

    private void AddSetStar(Ellipse star)
    {
        Canvas.SetTop(star, GameObject.Random.Next(GameObject.LEVEL_HEIGHT));
        Canvas.SetLeft(star, GameObject.Random.Next(GameObject.LEVEL_WIDTH));
        Panel.SetZIndex(star, 0);

        _gameField.Children.Add(star);
        _stars.Add(star);

    }

    private void _blinkingTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadingHelper.ThreadingAction(() =>
        {
            Ellipse star = _stars.ElementAt(GameObject.Random.Next(STAR_COUNT));
            _gameField.Children.Remove(star);
            _stars.Remove(star);
            var newStar = StarFactory.CreateStar();
            AddSetStar(newStar);
        });
    }
```

The StarFactory just creates such an Ellipse and returns it.
What I dont get: The

```
_gameField.Children.Remove(star);
```

works only for the Stars I add in the Constructor. The Stars I add on the Timer are not found on the Children-List.

I really have no idea, how this Elements can not be found since I add newly created Stars everytime on both lists.

P.S.: The ThreadingAction is just a helper to work on the UI-Thread:

```
    internal static void ThreadingAction(Action action)
    {
        if (Thread.CurrentThread == Application.Current.Dispatcher.Thread)
            action();
        else 
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
    }
```

Edit: The reason why I'm holding two lists is this:
If I want to work with the List, I use:

```
_stars.ForEach(f =>
```

Without this, I'd have to

```
        _gameField.Children.OfType<Ellipse>().ToList().ForEach(f => )
```

This is 2 Enumerations, one for OfType and one for ToList.
And what If I add other ellipses, which are not Stars?

About the Construction of the Stars: I do this only on two positions: In the Timer-Elapsed Event and in the Constructor. Does the Children-List not point to the objects then?
So the Stars are the same references, since I add the same reference everytime in both Lists.

Comment: *This means I can work just with the local List and dont have to recheck the Children-Collection every time*... there is no benefit to doing this. The `Children` collection points to a certain location in memory and your collection points to another... virtually no difference.

Comment: just made a demo and looks like it works OK, the `Remove()` works OK, how could you know that it did not work? to see it in action more clearly, you should set the `Interval` to a small value, such as `10`.

Comment: I think the problem might lie in another List, which holds the references as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of problems with your code. I shall attempt to address each in turn. First, you said that you

> add newly created stars to the Canvas (which holds more objects) and to a local list. This means I can work just with the local List and dont have to recheck the Children-Collection every time

However, there is no benefit to doing this. The `Children` collection points to a certain location in memory and your collection points to another... virtually no difference.

> *What I dont get: The `Children.Remove(star)` works only for the Stars I add in the Constructor*

That is because you can only remove an item from the collection *if that exact item* is in the collection. Therefore, you cannot generate a new object with certain property values and expect that to equal another object with identical property values... they are different objects in memory. So, to get around this, you can use `LinQ` to do something like this:

```
_gameField.Children.Remove(_gameField.Children[0]);
```

However, I believe that your final error is that you shouldn't be removing and re-adding these objects into the `Children` collection as you are anyway. Instead, it makes more sense to leave the objects in the `Children` collection and merely change their `Visiblity` values from `Visible` to `Hidden` and back repeatedly... perhaps something like this:

```
foreach (UIElement element in Canvas.Children)
{
    element.Visibility = element.Visibility == Visibility.Hidden ? 
        Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

Comment: ... and you expect me to answer your question again? Maybe you should have provided *all of the relevant information* to start with?

Comment: Well, your idea with the visibility was good, I create just more stars and make them invisible or visible.
I think you're right, creating so many objects is not a good idea and not needed.

Thanks so far